# Clickable form with editable fields with ng-click

Tags: edit, angularjs-ng-click

I am building an address book where users can edit fields as they click on them. I found this fiddle via a thread:
http://jsfiddle.net/timriley/GVCP2/

But it does not explain how to do with with a JSON style data source. As a beginner in Angularjs I am struggling to find a way to bind the editable forms to the data model so my attempt is pretty poor:

```
function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.contacts = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "Name": "Betty",
      "Surname": "Smith",
      "Address": "24 Funny Avenue, wc149m, London, United Kingdom"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "Name": "Anabella",
      "Surname": "Vicks",
      "Address": "19 Euston Road n12clm, London, Isle of Man"
    }];


  $scope.editorEnabled = false;

  $scope.enableEditor = function() {
    $scope.editorEnabled = true;
    $scope.editableAddress = $scope.contacts.Address;
  };

  $scope.disableEditor = function() {
    $scope.editorEnabled = false;
  };

  $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.contacts = $scope.editableAddress;
    $scope.disableEditor();
  };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/

How do I make all fields editable and updatable in the JSON array?

Answer (score 0):

Forget the messy question above. I found this brilliant AngularJS Bundle I wish I knew about 2 days ago: http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/.

FIXED